# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell,Design Version=14.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly

When I try to save a form after doing some after doing some changes am getting an error as

'Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design Version=144.0.0.0 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.' I am using Visual studio 2013 Professional.

[image]

Comment: Is that your Project? It looks like it's created with a newer version of VS (2015?). *try to save my file after doing some changes* is quite vague, anyway.

Comment: 14.0 = VS2015, it looks like you installed an extension (version control?) what references VS2015 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by changing the oldVersion to "14.0.0.0" of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design assembly in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ devenv.exe.config

[image]